# How can I set the position of the website at middle/center of the window?

Tags: css, layout, html

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/** General Style Info **/
body {
    background: #003d4c;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'lucida grande',verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:90%;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    text-align: left;
}

#content {
    background: #ffffff;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 970px;
}
```

The content division is inside container division.

The website is built in CRT monitor, but when i browse this website on LCD monitor with high resolution, i see that there are more space at the right side of the website.

The content or the website is not set in the middle of the window.

How can i set it at middle of the window so that the left and the right side are equally away from the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I have always done it:

```
body
{
    text-align: centre;
    //...
}

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; // resets alignment for rest of site
    width: 970px; // or whatever it needs to be
    //...
}
```

And it works in most resolutions (tested on 1024x768, 1360x768, 1920x1080 and never heard of problems from people using different resolutions).

Comment: +1 for text-align center on the body for backwards compatibility

Comment: Why text-align: center in body, it's overriden in #container with text-align: left;

Comment: @guru Because it centres everything, which makes the `#container` div centred (along with the margin). Unless you want _all_ text on your site centre-aligned, resetting the `text-align` property is just common sense.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to do this is wrap it in another div that has margins set to auto with a specific width.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 970px;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px,10px,10px,10px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: you just set a margin: auto on an element that is set to 100%; so it will never be in the center

Comment: @CBRRacer, it will never be in the center ?

Comment: @guru if you have an element with width: 100% (which a div has by default) then if you set margin: 0 auto; on that element it has nothing to pad since the edge of the element goes to the edge of the display area.  What margin: 0 auto; does is to allow the browser to determine the total horizontal margin and then split it between left and right so that they have equal margin from the parent element the 0 sets the top and bottom margin to 0

Comment: Forgot to add the width, put that in.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
text-align:center;
padding: 10px,10px,10px,10px;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;

}
```

Comment: It's not about text, it's about position of the content division.

Answer (score -1):

When you center align an element you need to give it a width either percentage (for liquid design) or fixed.

```
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

#content {margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;}
```

With your revisions all you have to do is set the

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
```

and that will center that element to the middle of it's parent which is assumed (since there is no code showing otherwise) that the parent is set to 100%